# How to create a tooltip menu panel which is similar to the Google Chrome developer tools tooltip?

Tags: html, css, vue.js, tailwind-css, tooltip

I want to create a custom tooltip menu which shows some messages when I hover over a text using the `Tailwind css` class and `@headlessui/vue`. I want this tooltip menu should be something similar to what we see when we inspect an element in Google Chrome. When we inspect the element it shows the tooltip something like this:
[image]

I want to build something similar in my `Nuxt 3` application using the Tailwind CSS class. I also want to include the pointer kind of thing which points to the text on which I have hovered. I was able to develop the menu but I am unable to create that pointer which points to the text.

Can someone please let me know how to develop the tooltip to something similar to Google Chromes inspection using the `Tailwind css` class and `@headlessui/vue`. Following is the code I have which shows the message when I hover over the text but does not add the pointer towards the text.

1. Add a pointer towards the text.
2. Ensure that height and width do not change based on the content, if the content is large then add a scrollbar so the menu does not expand.

Following is the code I have so far:

```
<template>
  <Popover v-slot="{ open, close }">
    <PopoverButton class="focus:outline-none">
      <span
        @mouseover.native.stop.prevent="hoverPopover($event, open)"
        @mouseleave.native.stop.prevent="closePopover($event, close)"
      >
        Hover Me
      </span>
    </PopoverButton>

    <PopoverPanel
      class="absolute z-50 dark:bg-gray-700 dark:text-white bg-gray-300 text-black rounded-lg px-3 py-2 text-sm font-normal inline-block ring-1 ring-black ring-opacity-5 focus:outline-none md:px-4 md:py-3 lg:px-5 lg:py-4 tooltip shadow-lg"
      @mouseover.native.stop.prevent="popoverHover = true"
      @mouseleave.native.stop.prevent="closePopover($event, close)"
    >
      <slot> Hover Text On Hover </slot>
    </PopoverPanel>
  </Popover>
</template>
  
<script setup>
import { Popover, PopoverButton, PopoverPanel, Portal } from "@headlessui/vue";

const popoverHover = ref(false);
const popoverTimeout = ref();

//On hover show the tooltip with information
const hoverPopover = (e, open) => {
  popoverHover.value = true;
  if (!open) {
    e.target.parentNode.click();
  }
};

//On mouse leave close it
const closePopover = (e, close) => {
  popoverHover.value = false;
  if (popoverTimeout.value) clearTimeout(popoverTimeout.value);
  popoverTimeout.value = setTimeout(() => {
    if (!popoverHover.value) {
      close();
    }
  }, 100);
};
</script>
```